# Css Style on navbar Hover

Tags: html, css

How can I make hover on the height of `li` see this picture  the hover applied just on  small size. I want it to take all the size.

[image]

I want it to take all space  like this selected image:
[image]

CSS

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px
}
li:hover  {
   color:white;
   background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<nav>

   <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current"><?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?></a></li>
      <li class="current"><a href="index-1.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_ABOUT_US']; ?></a></li>
     <li><a href="#services"><?php echo $lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS']; ?></a></li>
     <li><a href="index-4.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US']; ?></a></li>
     <li><a href="index-2.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_History']; ?></a></li>
  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: ok done I added The  html and css

Comment: snippet not added properly

Comment: there is typo mistake in your css.. remove space between li hover:  `li:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution............

**//css**

```
.nav-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .nav-list > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
  .nav-list > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .nav-list > li > a:hover,
  .nav-list > li > a:focus {
    background-color: orange;
    outline: 0;
  }
  .nav-list > .active > a,
  .nav-list > .active > a:hover,
  .nav-list > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: orange;
    outline: 0;
  }
```

html

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current"><?php echo $lang['MENU_HOME']; ?></a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="index-1.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_ABOUT_US']; ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="#services"><?php echo $lang['MENU_OUR_PRODUCTS']; ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="index-4.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_CONTACT_US']; ?></a></li>
    <li><a href="index-2.html"><?php echo $lang['MENU_History']; ?></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  
</head>
   <style> nav li{ padding:25px; } nav li:hover{ color:white !important; background-color:orange; } </style> 
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html" class="current">one</a></li>
         <li>two</li>
    
         <li><a href="#services">three</a></li>
         <li><a href="index-4.html">four</a></li>
         <li><a href="index-2.html">five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh then its so simple dude....just add padding for ur li tag like <style>
nav li{

padding:25px;
}
nav li:hover{

color:white !important;
background-color:orange;

}
</style>

Comment: yaar you dint mentioned how to proceed with or with out bootstrap...i thought u were working with bootstrap